# IE exported file not saving in proper format

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatables

I have a jquery datatable code that downloads table data as an excel file. It is working well in chrome but in IE the file is downloaded as 'File"' Type. The format shown by save as dialog box is *.all file

See this ex in link. Click on excel button in IE.

http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

Thanks All

Comment: Although it shows as * file type, both Chrome and IE are saving as .csv - is it just that you want the Save As box to show Excel CSV in the File Type box?

Comment: In chrome its showing option to save it as .xls file. By default save as excel option is showing in save as box. But in IE only *.all file is showing.

Comment: In chrome im able to save it as excel format not in IE. I wandor if there is any fix for IE

Comment: What IE version is it?

Comment: @leddy: I want In IE save as box shows option like xls or csv. Cause my users dont know to save filename.csv everytime

Comment: They don't need to put the .csv, it will automatically save as that

Comment: In the example page you linked to, all of the browsers give me a CSV file for both the CVS and Excel options. I don't get an excel file download from any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Force the filename / extension type by setting the `sFileName` - the following will force the filename to be `export.xls` as default in IE as well :

```js
var table = $("#example").dataTable({
    oTableTools: {
        aButtons: [
            { sExtends: "xls",
              mColumns: "visible",
              sFileName: "export.xls",
              sFieldSeperator: ";",
              sToolTip: "Save as Excel file"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

NB: Using dataTables 1.9.x notation since I dont know what version you are using, it works in all versions.